# Lacking of water or Lack of water

Tags: grammar, gerunds, bare-infinitives

Which of the following sentences is grammatically correct?

1. Lacking of water makes Death Valley a desert, but it is by no means devoid.
2. Lack of water makes Death Valley a desert, but it is by no means devoid.

Comment: If you look at this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lacking+of+water%2Clack+of+water&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) for "lacking of water,lack of water" you can see that the first version has about zero results.

Comment: Idiomatically, you can't use a gerund (*-ing* form used as a noun) in exactly that contexts (where the ***lacking*** actually *requires* some kind of modifier such as ***of water***). The explicit noun ***lack*** is "acceptable" in example #2, but I think most people would include an article (either ***A*** or ***The*** before ***lack***.

Comment: ...on the other hand,  [***Murdering** of unwanted children is a distasteful aspect of some cultures*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22murdering+of+unwanted+children%22) doesn't seem any worse than [*The **murder** of unwanted children is a...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+murder+of+unwanted+children%22) to me. Perhaps it's the sentiment rather than the syntax. I certainly can't explain exactly what's going on here, but I don't *think* OP's example #1 is syntactically invalid - it's just not at all idiomatic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think it's that "murder" is an action verb while "lack" is a non-action verb. I haven't had enough caffeine yet to try and disprove this, but it feels right.

Comment: @gotube: After you've had your coffee, I wonder if you'll be able to think of another word that's both a noun and a "non-action" verb, same as ***lack***. It took me a couple of minutes to even think of a word that could be both noun and verb ***and*** be modified by an ***of-*** based prepositional element. And even then, ***murder*** isn't exactly comparable, because (so long as not preceded by an article) ***Murder** is a distasteful aspect...* still makes sense, but ***Lack** makes Death Valley a desert...* doesn't work at all. Not sure about ***Murdering** is a distasteful...,* though.

Comment: @Cheng: I think you've put the cat among the pigeons here! (Done something *disruptive*). This looks to me like a very subtle aspect of what is or isn't *idiomatically* acceptable, rather than "grammatically correct". If you don't mind, I might try asking about it on English Language and Usage, where there might be people with more relevant knowledge about what's really going on, syntactically speaking.

Comment: As an aside, simply saying "it is by no means devoid." isn't very clear or idiomatic.  [We almost always say "devoid **of  (something)**"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/devoid), and leaving out the "of something" leaves it unclear what Death Valley is missing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Want" fits the bill, and even has roughly the same meaning, to boot. (And it's tea, not coffee.)

Comment: @stangdon: Absolutely! You can be ***bereft*** without being specifically bereft ***of*** whatever you no longer have, but you can't normally just be ***devoid*** (of unspecified things).